# Why is my `CREATE DATABASE foo` returning a SQLCODE=-104 on DB2?

Tags: db2, ddl

Connected to a DB2 instance, I am trying to run a `CREATE DATABASE foo`, through JDBC, but am getting the following error:

`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=database;create ;TABLESPACE, DRIVER=4.16.53 [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=-104]`

This seems to be the code for a [SQL syntax error](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n104.html) (not "permission denied", or some other error). But `CREATE DATABASE foo` looks valid to me based on the description of the [create database command](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE DATABASE` is not an SQL statement, but rather a DB2 CLP command so it can't be executed via JDBC (not even via the `ADMIN_CMD()` procedure.